Does reading to your children unfairly disadvantage Others?
National Review writes

Professor: If You Read To Your Kids, You’re ‘Unfairly Disadvantaging’ Others

According to the article the statement was done during "an interview with ABC Radio" by philosopher and professor Adam Swift, who is associated with University of Warwick in England
Full quote in the article is less harsh.

“I don’t think parents reading their children bedtime stories should constantly have in their minds the way that they are unfairly disadvantaging other people’s children, but I think they should have that thought occasionally,” he said.


Did Adam Swift make these the claims in the article?

Does reading to your children cause advantage?



If so, is this unfair? (I'm sure Warwick has definition of unfair in his body of work if he has made these claims.)




"If so, is this unfair?" I don’t think this is answerable. Trivially there is a relative disadvantage if some have an advantage, but "unfair" seems like a subjective or at least ambiguous rating.

The National Review article cites The Philosopher's Zone wherein he is quoted as saying "You have to allow parents to engage in bedtime stories activities, in fact we encourage them because those are the kinds of interactions between parents and children that do indeed foster and produce these [desired] familial relationship goods."  The National Review instead quotes this sentence as: "bedtime stories activities ... do indeed foster and produce ... [desired] familial relationship goods".

Is this position fundamentally different from the idea that feeding one's children a nutritious breakfast "unfairly disadvantages Others"? That's not rhetorical; I'm trying to understand what the claim actually means.

Specifically, what claim is this question skeptical about? That the quotation is falsely attributed to Swift? That reading gives people an advantage? That life isn't fair? These all seem trivially true facts, with no obvious reason for skepticism.

@RayButterworth This whole issue smells like a quote-minded from larger theoretical description of a thought experiment. Hence, the question has been split: 1) Did he make these claims. 2) Is the foundation solid 3) Does he use it to make the point that it seems to layman.

ABC Listen published an article based on the interview, with a significant number of quotes: Is having a loving family an unfair advantage?. The quote from Swift that best summarizes his position is:

‘We could prevent elite private schooling without any real hit to healthy family relationships, whereas if we say that you can’t read bedtime stories to your kids because it’s not fair that some kids get them and others don’t, then that would be too big a hit at the core of family life.’

This clearly explains the unfairness: only some kids get bedtime stories read to them.
It would also seem that the National Review lost some important context from the original source (emphasis added):

‘I don’t think parents reading their children bedtime stories should constantly have in their minds the way that they are unfairly disadvantaging other people’s children, but I think they should have that thought occasionally,’ quips Swift.

As for the developmental benefits of reading aloud, there are sources aplenty online, such as Why Reading Aloud to Kids Helps Them Thrive.

The omission of context and rephrasing by National Review changes the tone of the statement significantly. "Some kids don't get read bedtime stories because their parents don't have time or don't care enough, and that sucks for them" becomes "Professor claims that if you read bedtime stories to your kid you're a terrible person because other kids don't get stories" . Of course, we're expected to presume good faith reporting, but still...

I'd agree, but there is this somewhat strange suggestion for parents: "… the way that they are unfairly disadvantaging other people’s children, … I think they should have that thought occasionally". As a parent, I often had that thought, though not in those exact words, and not in the same way he apparently meant it.

@Shadur-don't-feed-the-AI Regarding "Of course, we're expected to presume good faith reporting, but still..." From the National Review? It's best not to expect good faith reporting from them.

@RayButterworth I think it is important to note the quote says the Professor quips this and not just said this. quip to me implies some non seriousness.

@davidhammen I will agree that the word "lost" is doing some Olympic Gold Medalist grade heavy lifting, yes, but by this site's guidelines we're expected to not bring our political opinions into our answers.

"Unfairly disadvantaging" might be a somewhat clumsy choice of words here. Arguably, this is about giving some children an advantage, not holding back other children, and so might better be described as "advantaging," and what is unfair is arguably more that some parents do not have time to read bedtime stories to their children (presumably, the societal factors that prevent them from doing so are indeed "unfairly disadvantaging" their children).

In that same vein, it's a little surprising to see that they discuss ways to promote interfamilial equality of opportunity by restricting unfair advantages, instead of universalizing them, at least in the interview. E.g. they discuss preventing parents from sending their children to elite private schools, but not increasing taxes and redistributing funding to bring all public schools up to the same educational level. Similarly, guaranteeing minimum time off and universal basic income might be way of ensuring that all parents have time to interact with their children.
